# When to use views and layouts vs OpenGL ES based framework

Tags: android, opengl-es

In a book about game development for Android I read that using Views and layout produces a lot of overhead and moving them around may cause bad user experience due to stuttering.

Now I'm wondering from what amount of views or redraws per second onwards is it definitely better to use some kind of graphic framework?

Comment: Are you wondering about any graphic framework vs Open GL or Android views in particular?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I'm more interested to know about vs Android views in particular as far as i understand it all graphic frameworks for android are extensions of open GL so it doesn't really matter which kind of framework it is